# How do I save a String to a text file using Java?

Tags: java, file, file-io, text-files

In Java, I have text from a text field in a String variable called "text".

How can I save the contents of the "text" variable to a file?

Answer (score 817):

If you're simply outputting text, rather than any binary data, the following will work:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");
```

Then, write your String to it, just like you would to any output stream:

```
out.println(text);
```

You'll need exception handling, as ever. Be sure to close the output stream when you've finished writing.

```
out.close()
```

If you are using Java 7 or later, you can use the "[try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)" which will automatically close your `PrintStream` when you are done with it (ie exit the block) like so:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt")) {
    out.println(text);
}
```

You will still need to explicitly throw the `java.io.FileNotFoundException` as before.

Comment: What's exception handling? Where will this file be saved?

Comment: it'll be saved in the current directory, whatever that is as far as the JVM is concerned. Exception handling is the try{} catch(){} stuff you see in other answers :)

Comment: @Justin, you could also pass an absolute path (e.g. "/tmp/filename.txt") to the FileOutputStream constructor, to save the file anywhere you want

Comment: Btw, this could be simplified using the convenience constructors PrintStream has had since 1.5. This would suffice: PrintStream out = new PrintStream("filename.txt");

Comment: Futhermore, as we're outputting text, PrintWriter would be more appropriate, and just as convenient. From PrintStream javadocs: "The PrintWriter class should be used in situations that require writing characters rather than bytes."

Comment: Need to close that file though at some point...?  http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/ASCII_file_save#Java

Comment: new PrintWriter(file).println(output); results in 0 byte file. Output is a string of 6000 chars...No matter if the file exists already or not...

Comment: @Sloin @Devolus Did you make sure to call `out.close()`? It writes an empty file if the PrintWriter is garbage-collected before it's flushed or closed, but if you `close()` it correctly it writes the file.

Comment: You want to use  try{} catch(){}finally{}, where in finally{} you close the file if it is not null.

Comment: In java8 you can try(PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("filename")) { ps.println(out); } this will handle close for you

Comment: Regarding @AntonChikin comment above: you can also do this in Java 7

Comment: out.flush(); after this line only i can see data in my file

Comment: What string encoding does this use?

Answer (score 280):

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io) contains some great methods for doing this, in particular FileUtils contains the following method:

```
static void writeStringToFile(File file, String data, Charset charset)
```

which allows you to write text to a file in one method call:

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("test.txt"), "Hello File", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

You might also want to consider specifying the encoding for the file as well.

Comment: Just a minor correction, the second fragment should read: FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("test.txt"), "Hello File");

Comment: For those of us who prefer Guava, [it can do this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java/11254277#11254277).

Comment: The function is now deprecated, you should add the default charset --> `FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("test.txt"), "Hello File", forName("UTF-8"));`

Answer (score 140):

In Java 7 you can do this:

```
String content = "Hello File!";
String path = "C:/a.txt";
Files.write( Paths.get(path), content.getBytes());
```

There is more info here:
http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/java-se-7-new-file-io/231600403

Comment: In case someone later wondered, the encoding would be the platform standard.

Comment: `content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` can be used to explicitly define the encoding.

Comment: Note that StandardOpenOption.CREATE is not the default one StandardOpenOption.CREATE and StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING is the default. To use the default just remove the third parameter.

Comment: Please see Tinus Tate's comment!  What is the process to edit this example?  I wonder how many thousands of people have taken this example as-is only to find that they have unexpected results when they overwrite a file with a shorter string.  As Tinus indicates, TRUNCATE_EXISTING is crucial unless you fully understand and have an actual reason for not wanting to truncate the existing file when overwriting with a shorter string.

Comment: In java 11 you can simply put a String as a second parameter! Hooray!

Comment: But you have to use `writeString()` instead of `write()` then, right?

Answer (score 114):

Take a look at the [Java File API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

a quick example:

```
try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("filename.txt"))) {
    out.print(text);
}
```

Comment: @XP1 I know, that's a great improvement. I've used Lombok for this in Java 6: just go `@Cleanup new FileOutputStream(...)` and you're done.

Comment: Don't forget to call out.flush(); then out.close();

Comment: @AlexByrth why should he?

Comment: Large files are recorded in the background (another thread) and take time to record. Calling flush () ensures that everything has been written on the next line, synchronizing the operation. But this is *optional*, but good practice if you handle large files, as logs.

Comment: Note that out.close() already flushes the stream, which means it is not necessary to call out.flush().

Comment: What about the string encoding? Best practices ask to always specify the encoding.

Answer (score 83):

Just did something similar in my project. Use [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) will simplify part of your job. And here you can find nice [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/index.html).

```
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try
{
    writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( yourfilename));
    writer.write( yourstring);

}
catch ( IOException e)
{
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        if ( writer != null)
        writer.close( );
    }
    catch ( IOException e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing all try/catch and simplify it I'm also able to do it in one line just by doing the: (new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( filename))).write(str);

Comment: Wrapping a FileWriter in a BufferedWriter is superfluous when you're writing out the entire file in a single `write()` call.

Comment: It seems that `.close()` doesn't throw (at least in Java 7?), is the last trycatch perhaps redundant?

Comment: Swallowing exceptions like that is going to make life hard for you when exceptions really do occur. At the very least you should rethrow them: `throw new RuntimeException(e);`

Answer (score 70):

Use `FileUtils.writeStringToFile()` from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io). No need to reinvent this particular wheel.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more. These libraries are there so we don't introduce subtle bugs in such a simple solution.

Comment: Would you suggest that he go back and re-implement java.file.IO and java.io.PrintStream in raw C? Of course not. You use the java.io abstractions, and save your effort for real problems. And Commons IO is a better abstraction than java.io when it comes to this particular problem.

Comment: No, obviously not.  I'm only disagreeing that your solution might not be the first thing I'd throw at someone who's a beginner Java programmer.  You aren't suggesting that you've never written such a thing, are you?

Comment: I have, yes, but that's before I found commons-io. Since finding that, I've never written that sort of thing by hand, even in a one-class project. If I'd known about it from day one, I'd have used it from day one.

Comment: Exactly, but you're an experienced developer.  Your bio says your a JBOSS/Spring user, but certainly you wouldn't have been up to either one in your first "Hello, World" effort.  I'm not disagreeing with the proper use of libraries.  I'm saying that people attempting a language for the first time should try to know it at its bottom, even if that means doing things that they'll discard later on when they're experienced and know better.

Comment: I implemented this without commons and got a less than obvious exception thrown.  I then implemented this using commons and it told me exactly what was wrong.  Moral of the story: why live in the dark ages if you don't have to?

Comment: @duffymo: well Commons way now moved to [Java 7](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22445604/281545) anyway :D

Comment: +1 for using a well-known library. We still need answers "from the bottom" and oriented to "experienced" developers

Answer (score 58):

In **Java 11** the `java.nio.file.Files` class was extended by two new utility methods to write a string into a file. The first method (see JavaDoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#writeString(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.charset.Charset,java.nio.file.OpenOption...))) uses the charset [UTF-8](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8) as default:

```
Files.writeString(Path.of("my", "path"), "My String");
```

And the second method (see JavaDoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#writeString(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.file.OpenOption...))) allows to specify an individual charset:

```
Files.writeString(Path.of("my", "path"), "My String", StandardCharset.ISO_8859_1);
```

Both methods have an optional Varargs parameter for setting file handling options (see JavaDoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html)). The following example would create a non-existing file or append the string to an existing one:

```
Files.writeString(Path.of("my", "path"), "String to append", StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Comment: This needs more upvotes. The answer gets buried in the amount of answers provided to this question, yet it is superior to many of them. *E.g.* only a minimal amount of lines is required, there is also no dependency on Apache Commons.

Comment: I second above comment, this is an elegant solution !!

Comment: One can also write: Path.of("my/path")

Answer (score 25):

You can use the modify the code below to write your file from whatever class or function is handling the text.  One wonders though why the world needs a new text editor...

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String str = "SomeMoreTextIsHere";
            File newTextFile = new File("C:/thetextfile.txt");

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
            fw.write(str);
            fw.close();

        } catch (IOException iox) {
            //do stuff with exception
            iox.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't close the file in case of an exception.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: If rejected, cite [*The try-with-resources Statement*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 16):

I prefer to rely on libraries whenever possible for this sort of operation. This makes me less likely to accidentally omit an important step (like mistake wolfsnipes made above). Some libraries are suggested above, but my favorite for this kind of thing is [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Guava has a class called [Files](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) which works nicely for this task:

```
// This is where the file goes.
File destination = new File("file.txt");
// This line isn't needed, but is really useful 
// if you're a beginner and don't know where your file is going to end up.
System.out.println(destination.getAbsolutePath());
try {
    Files.write(text, destination, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Useful error handling here
}
```

Comment: If you're using Guava, there is also `Charsets.UTF-8`.

Comment: @florian: It's `Charsets.UTF_8` actually

Comment: The parent folder must exist. Example: destination.mkdirs().

Comment: Files.write(CharSequence from, File to, Charset charset) is deprecated in guava 26.0.

Comment: Modern Guava alternative to deprecated Files.write: 
`Files.asCharSink(file, charset).write(text)`

Answer (score 15):

In case if you need create text file based on one single string:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class StringWriteSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "This is text to be saved in file";

        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get("my-file.txt"), text.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Files.write(path, byte[]) will use UTF-8 encoding. String.getBytes() uses the default platform encoding. So this is a potential issue. Use string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)!

Answer (score 14):

Using `Java 7`:

```
public static void writeToFile(String text, String targetFilePath) throws IOException
{
    Path targetPath = Paths.get(targetFilePath);
    byte[] bytes = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Files.write(targetPath, bytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
}
```

Comment: A word to the wise - this will create a new file if it isn't there, but will overwrite the characters of the existing file if it is. If the new data is smaller, that will mean you probably create a corrupted file. Ask me how I know!

Comment: Ok, how do you know?

Comment: Just use `Files.write(targetPath, bytes);` to overwrite the file then. It will work as expected.

Answer (score 13):

Use Apache Commons IO api. Its simple

Use API as

```
 FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("FileNameToWrite.txt"), "stringToWrite");
```

Maven Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 12):

Use this, it is very readable:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

Files.write(Paths.get(path), lines.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
```

Comment: It's also a copy of an existing answer.  :c

Comment: sorry but i didn't invent java8 , i am not the only one that use this line . but it is not a copy past from other answers to the same question

Answer (score 11):

You could do this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class WriteText
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        try {
            String text = "Your sample content to save in a text file.";
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("sample.txt"));
            out.write(text);
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception ");       
        }

        return ;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 11):

```
import java.io.*;

private void stringToFile( String text, String fileName )
 {
 try
 {
    File file = new File( fileName );

    // if file doesnt exists, then create it 
    if ( ! file.exists( ) )
    {
        file.createNewFile( );
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter( file.getAbsoluteFile( ) );
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( fw );
    bw.write( text );
    bw.close( );
    //System.out.println("Done writing to " + fileName); //For testing 
 }
 catch( IOException e )
 {
 System.out.println("Error: " + e);
 e.printStackTrace( );
 }
} //End method stringToFile
```

You can insert this method into your classes. If you are using this method in a class with a main method, change this class to static by adding the static key word. Either way you will need to import java.io.* to make it work otherwise File, FileWriter and BufferedWriter will not be recognized.

Answer (score 11):

Using org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils:

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("log.txt"), "my string", Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Answer (score 7):

If you only care about pushing one block of text to file, this will overwrite it each time.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    FileOutputStream stream = null;
    PrintStream out = null;
    try {
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        stream = new FileOutputStream(file); 
        String text = "Your String goes here";
        out = new PrintStream(stream);
        out.print(text);                  //This will overwrite existing contents

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //do something
    } finally {
        try {
            if(stream!=null) stream.close();
            if(out!=null) out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

This example allows the user to select a file using a file chooser.

Comment: @Eric Leschinski : thank you for making my answer more professional
(i also assumed this was exactly what the OP wanted since this is what actually most people wants,just dump the text and replace it)

Comment: Once the original question has been answered and the OP is satisfied and long-gone, pages like this serve only as a useful artifact to people who land here from a Google search.  I landed on this page in order to create a mini text appender to a file.  So it's good to speak to the entire audience rather than the OP after the OP has moved on.

Answer (score 6):

```java
private static void generateFile(String stringToWrite, String outputFile) {
    try {       
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFile);
        writer.append(stringToWrite);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        log.debug("New File is generated ==>"+outputFile);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        log.error("Exception in generateFile ", exp);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: close() may never be called. Please, improve your answer adding the proper error case handling.

Answer (score 6):

Basically the same answer [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1053474/26510), but easy to copy/paste, and it just works ;-)

```
  import java.io.FileWriter;

  public void saveToFile(String data, String filename) {
    try (
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename)) {
      fw.write(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

It's better to close the writer/outputstream in a finally block, just in case something happen

```
finally{
   if(writer != null){
     try{
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
     }
     catch(IOException ioe){
         ioe.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: even better: use try-with-resources

Comment: Yes, @JanusTroelsen is right, better use The try-with-resources statement https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is using `Files.write(Path path, Iterable<? extends CharSequence> lines, OpenOption... options)`:

```
String text = "content";
Path path = Paths.get("path", "to", "file");
Files.write(path, Arrays.asList(text));
```

See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)):

> Write lines of text to a file. Each line is a char sequence and is
>   written to the file in sequence with each line terminated by the
>   platform's line separator, as defined by the system property
>   line.separator. Characters are encoded into bytes using the specified
>   charset.
>
> The options parameter specifies how the the file is created or opened.
>   If no options are present then this method works as if the CREATE,
>   TRUNCATE_EXISTING, and WRITE options are present. In other words, it
>   opens the file for writing, creating the file if it doesn't exist, or
>   initially truncating an existing regular-file to a size of 0. The
>   method ensures that the file is closed when all lines have been
>   written (or an I/O error or other runtime exception is thrown). If an
>   I/O error occurs then it may do so after the file has created or
>   truncated, or after some bytes have been written to the file.

Please note. I see people have already answered with Java's built-in `Files.write`, but what's special in my answer which nobody seems to mention is the overloaded version of the method which takes an Iterable of  CharSequence (i.e. String), instead of a `byte[]` array, thus `text.getBytes()` is not required, which is a bit cleaner I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep the carriage return characters from the string into a file
here is an code example:

```
    jLabel1 = new JLabel("Enter SQL Statements or SQL Commands:");
    orderButton = new JButton("Execute");
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    ...


    // String captured from JTextArea()
    orderButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            // When Execute button is pressed
            String tempQuery = textArea.getText();
            tempQuery = tempQuery.replaceAll("\n", "\r\n");
            try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/Temp/tempQuery.sql"))) {
                out.print(tempQuery);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(tempQuery);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have published a library that saves files, and handles everything with one line of code only, you can find it here along with its documentation

[Github repository](https://github.com/rasmi-aw/StorageManager)

and the answer to your question is so easy

```
String path = FileSaver
        .get()
        .save(string.getBytes(),"file.txt");
```

Answer (score -1):

My way is based on stream due to running on all Android versions and needs of fecthing resources such as URL/URI, any suggestion is welcome.

As far as concerned, streams (InputStream and OutputStream) transfer binary data, when developer goes to write a string to a stream, must first convert it to bytes, or in other words encode it.

```
public boolean writeStringToFile(File file, String string, Charset charset) {
    if (file == null) return false;
    if (string == null) return false;
    return writeBytesToFile(file, string.getBytes((charset == null) ? DEFAULT_CHARSET:charset));
}

public boolean writeBytesToFile(File file, byte[] data) {
    if (file == null) return false;
    if (data == null) return false;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bos.write(data, 0, data.length);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.e("!!! IOException");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please add proper error case handling closing all opened resources and propogating exceptions