# How do you write a String to a text file?

Tags: java, string, text-files

I have a String that is storing the processed results for a few files.  How do I write that String to a .txt file in my project?  I have another String variable which is the desired name of the .txt file.

Comment: What have you searched for before asking this question?

Comment: Any code sample you already tried and it didn't work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I save a String to a text file using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java)

Comment: You could try using a FileWriter: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Put this at the top of the file:
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));

//Add this to write a string to a file
//
try {

    out.write("aString\nthis is a\nttest");  //Replace with the string 
                                             //you are trying to write
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("Exception ");

}
finally
{
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Better specify your encoding: try(BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ));) {
            out.write(content);
        }

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean like?

```
FileUtils.writeFile(new File(filename), textToWrite);
```

[FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) is available in Commons IO.

Comment: Although it is an old thread - which source is the FileUtils you are referring to?

Comment: @jamesdeath123 good suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Files that are created using byte-based streams represent data in binary format. Files created using character-based streams represent data as sequences of characters. Text files can be read by text editors, whereas binary files are read by a program that converts the data to a human-readable format.

Classes `FileReader` and `FileWriter` perform character-based file I/O.

If you are using Java 7, you can uses `try-with-resources` to shorten method considerably:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String str = "写字符串到文件"; // Chinese-character string
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt", "UTF-8")) {
            out.write(str);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use Java’s `try-with-resources` statement to automatically **close** resources (objects that must be closed when they are no longer needed). You should consider a resource class must implement the `java.lang.AutoCloseable` interface or its `java.lang.Closeable` subinterface.