# converting a string; keyboard entry in java

Tags: java, keyboard, markdown

I have this code for converting a markdown string to html:

```
public static String convert(String str) {
    if (str.equals("# "))
        return " ";

    if (str.matches("#+.+")) {
        int n = str.length() - str.replaceFirst("#+", "").length();
        return "<h" + n + ">" + str.substring(n) + "<h" + n + ">";
    }

    return str;
}
```

What I would like to know is how to get this class to get its string from keyboard entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Scanner.nextLine()`:

```
String stringToConvert = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
System.out.println("Converted string is: " + convert(stringToConvert));
```

Comment: I write this inside of the convert method or in the main?

Comment: You would put this in `main`.

Comment: and what do i do if i want my "program" to convert a document and return the solution in another one?

Comment: You would have to write the returned string to file. See this [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java).

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep it simple you can go by [`Console.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine%28%29).

Comment: No, you defined a method, you must pass the return value from `readLine` to your `convert` method.

Comment: so in my main i could write a=console.readline() and then in convert(string a) ?