# Most efficient way to write a string to a file

Tags: java, file, text, output

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I save a String to a text file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java)

I want to add a reading from a machine to a file (Java).
The reading will be in the form of a string that I have formatted. The file is just a text file. At the moment I am considering Filewriter/Buffered writer is this the correct one to use?

Comment: Usually the buffered readers are best but I would advise trying a couple of ways and then timing them. These things often have lots of factors affecting performance

Comment: What is a "reading"? Do you just want to write a string to a text file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) will do you job.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( yourfilename));
writer.write( yourstring);
// do stuff 
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are planning to use the JDK alone, you might want to consider wrapping your `BufferedWriter` with a `PrintWriter` as in

```
PrintWriter printWriter=new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter);
printWriter.println(yourString);
```

The printWriter comes with a nice `println` method.

Or if you are free to use external libraries, try [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) `writeStringToFile`

Answer (score 1):

Yup. Use `java.io.BufferedWriter`.