# using for loop write lines one by one in file using java

Tags: java, file-io

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    String output = output + "Result "+ i +" : "+ ans +"\n";   //ans from other logic
    FileWriter f0 = new FileWriter("output.txt");
    f0.write(output);
}
```

but it doesn't work,
please give some help for `append` or `PrintWriter` method, i have no idea how to use these methods.

i need file output like

```
Result 1 : 45           //here 45 is ans
Result 2 : 564856
Result 3 : 879
.
.
.
.
Result 10 : 564
```

thanks

Comment: Which thing doesn't work? Or any error occurs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I save a String to a text file using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your code is creating a new file for every line. Pull the file open outside of the for loop.

```
FileWriter f0 = new FileWriter("output.txt");

String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");


for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    f0.write("Result "+ i +" : "+ ans + newLine);
}
f0.close();
```

If you want to use `PrintWriter`, try this

```
PrintWriter f0 = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    f0.println("Result "+ i +" : "+ ans);
}
f0.close();
```

Comment: appending '\n' isn't very portable. you should use  a buffered writer wrapper then the `newLine();`

Answer (score 3):

PrintWriter.printf seems to be the most appropriate

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pw.printf("Result %d : %s %n",  i, ans);
    }
    pw.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try this :

```
FileWriter f0 = new FileWriter("output.txt");
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    f0.newLine();
    String output = output + "Result "+ i +" : "+ ans;   //ans from other logic
    f0.append(output);
}
```

Comment: I don't see newLine() method in the API

Comment: I don't see also.