# How to create a file & folder in Java?

Tags: java, file

**Okay, updated this right now**

As of now I have this:

```
File saveGame = new File(Config.saveDir,Config.saveName);
```

Now how would I create that into a text file? My saveDir has already been created (mkDir), and my saveName is defined as "xyz.txt", so what method do I use to create this file (and later add text into it)?

Comment: in your question, tell us what is happening, what is going wrong, what you expect to happen.

Comment: And ask a question...

Comment: To create a new file, you might have a look at `File.createNewFile()`.

Comment: EDIT: Here is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1053475/778118) that shows how to write text to a file.  I found it by googling "_java write text to file_" and clicking the first result (I originally posted the wrong link, sorry).  The accepted answer is best if you can use _Apache Commons IO_, but for homework the linked answer should be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

`new File(...)` doesn't crete a file on disk, it only creates a path for a Java program to use to refer to a file that may or may not exist on disk (hence the `File.exists()` method).

Try `userFile.createNewFile();` to actually create the file on disk.

To make the directory you would need to use the `File.mkdirs()` method, but don't call it on `userFile` or it will make a directory with the `Savegame.txt` in it.

Edit:

```
File dir = new File(Config.userpath + "/test/");
File file = new File(dir, "," + Config.name + " Savegame.txt");

dir.mkdir(); // should check to see if it succeeds (if(dir.mkdir())...)
file.createNewFile(); // should also check that this succeeds.
```

Comment: How exactly could I do this? A few lines of code would help :3