# How to create a mustache without using a file?

Tags: java, mustache

I have the template saved as a string somewhere and I want to create the mustache with that. How can I do this? Or is it doable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is the method I found:

```
private String renderMustacheContent() throws IOException {
    MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
    Mustache mustache;

    if (type.getTemplate().trim().isEmpty()) {            
        String emailContent = genCpuEmailContent(cmsKey);
        mustache = mf.compile(new StringReader(emailContent), "cpu.template.email");
    } else {
        mustache = mf.compile(type.getTemplate());
    }

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    mustache.execute(writer, values).flush();

    return writer.toString();
}
```

So, basically when you just want to render the email from a String template rather than a file, just create the new StringReader with the template.

Comment: what is `type` in this ?

Comment: just an enum class containing metadata for the template;; ie some have template some dont, with potential template file name

Answer (score 0):

If you store that String into a File using FileWriter (or some other classes) and keep the extension .mustache, then you should be able to close and use that file.  Here's something I whipped up real quick (it may not work):

```
//write to the file
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("template.mustache"), "example mustache stuff");
//do stuff....
//code for turning template into mustache
MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
Mustache mustache = mf.compile("template.mustache");
mustache.execute(new PrintWriter(System.out), new Example()).flush();
```

EDIT:  I misread the title.  You could create a temporary file, then delete it later.

Sources:

[How do I save a String to a text file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java)

https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java/blob/master/example/src/main/java/mustachejava/Example.java

Comment: that is doing too much for something that should be simple.

Comment: Writing to file might reduce the performance of the system. I think StringReader solution is better.