# How to save a servlet output from within a different servlet?

Tags: servlets

I have a servlet A and a servlet B, where servlet B returns a HTML.

Does anyone knows if its possible to make a call from within servlet A to servlet B and store its HTML response in a file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a servlet A from Servlet B you can do it using the RequestDispacher like this:

ServletA:

```
ServletContext sc = getServletContext();  
RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/ServletB");  
rd.forward(req, resp);
```

Then use the same code to redirect back to ServletA but store also the returned html in session so you can access it from ServletA

ServletB:

```
ServletContext sc = getServletContext();  
session.setAttribute("BHTML",html)
RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/ServletA");  
rd.forward(req, resp);
```

And then in ServletA get the html from session:

```
String html=request.getSession().getAttribute("BHTML").toString();
```

Then you can store that in a file like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java)