# How do I save the results of a calculation to a .txt file in java

Tags: java

Say I did a calculation:

1000 * 2000

How would I print the results of that calculation to a .txt file?

Comment: There is a tool called google. Try it ! It's awesome =) http://bit.ly/JHU2z8

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I save a String to a text file using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java)

Comment: I did and couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: @user3071724 If you're stuck on a specific part, post your code and explain what's the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PrintWriter` class. Something like:

```
PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter("filename.txt", "UTF-8");
w.println(calculation);
```

This will create a new file with the specified name, or it will  overwrite one if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think your have trouble with variable types. Convert the Int to String. I haven't tried the code.

```
Integer.toString(1000 * 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void saveAs() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Type In The New File Name"); //FILE NAME CHOICE
        Scanner fileChoice = new Scanner(System.in); //this scans userinput
        String newFile;                             //this is userinput
        newFile = fileChoice.nextLine();           //whatever they type is stored in this var
        File fileWriter = new File(newFile);       //opens a new file
        PrintWriter writeNew = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(newFile, true));  //writes to it
        writeNew.println("TEXT HERE BLAH")         //writes the text to that file
        writeNew.close();                          //and dont forget to close
```

when the userinput will ask you for file name SPECIFY IT IS .TXT eg. type in hello.txt

problemsolved-