# Java code to save a variable to a a text file

Tags: java

I need code to write a single line like `Aidan Dowling` to a text file.
My code so far is:

```
package battleships.startmenu;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Startmenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hello! Please enter your first name: ");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a;
        String b;
        a=reader.next();
        System.out.print("Enter your second name: ");
        b=reader.next();

        System.out.println("Hello " + a+ " " + b + "!");
        System.out.println("\tHello");
        String name;
        name = a + b;
    }
}
```

I want the variable name to print out to a document called name.txt

Comment: What did you try? What is the relation between your question and the code you pasted?

Comment: Try looking at the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html).

Comment: This question probably contains all the information you want:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java

Comment: Use a `PrintWriter`. It works a lot like `System.out` but it writes to a file.

Comment: The class for writing a file is aptly named `FileWriter`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Comment: I was there 10 minutes ago. It was confusing :S

Comment: Why is this question voted down? The other one was way too complicated!

Answer (score 2):

create a writer

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("name.txt", "UTF-8");
```

write a line

```
writer.println(name);
```

close the writer

```
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing `name` to `name.txt`:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("name.txt"), Arrays.asList(name), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```