# Reading .txt file and converting to .csv file

Tags: java, csv, filewriter, printwriter

Having trouble converting data from a .txt file into a .csv file. Everything runs pretty clean but when it converts to the .csv file it only displays partial data from the .txt file. .txt file is input.txt
Here's what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import com.csvreader.CsvWriter;

public class InputOutputExample
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the name and file type: ");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        String studentInfo = inputFile.nextLine();

        System.out.println(studentInfo);

        CsvWriter outputFile = new CsvWriter("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\output.csv");
        outputFile.write(studentInfo);
        outputFile.close();

    }



    inputFile.close();

}
```

}

Output in Java Program:

```
Enter the name and file type: 
input.txt [Enter]

Student_Id, student_name, gender, grade

993541, Ricky, male, A
037832, Joanne, female, A
034442, Amanda, female, B
054335, Logan, male, B
042343, Paul, male, B

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When converted to .csv it only displays `42343, Paul, male, B` in the cells

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse .txt to .csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526679/parse-txt-to-csv)

Comment: you are crating new csv file in every while loop iteration

Answer (score 1):

You should remove csv file creating out of while loop:

```
CsvWriter outputFile = new CsvWriter("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\output.csv");

while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    String studentInfo = inputFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println(studentInfo);
    outputFile.write(studentInfo);
    outputFile.newLine();
}

outputFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extract `CsvWriter outputFile = new CsvWriter("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\output.csv");` from while loop and `outputFile.close();` also.
The code should be like this:

`CsvWriter outputFile = new CsvWriter("C:\Users\John\Desktop\output.csv");
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        String studentInfo = inputFile.nextLine();

```
    System.out.println(studentInfo);

    outputFile.write(studentInfo);
}
```

outputFile.close();`

Try with above code replacement