# How to split a text file containing multiple JSONs to string arrays where each array element contains single json?

Tags: java, json

/*1*/
{
  "ZZ" : 123,
  "CC" : {
    "A" : false,
    "D" : false
  },
  "C" : false
}

/*2*/
{
  "ZZ" : 12123,
  "CC" : {
    "A" : false,
    "D" : false
  },
  "C" : false
}

I'm trying to convert this file to excel in csv format but error occurs due to the presence of multiple JSONs.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.github.opendevl.JFlat;

public class JSON2CSV {
public static void main(String myHelpers[]) throws Exception{
    String[] str;
    try {
        str = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D:\\My File_674335\\csvConversion\\inputJSON.json"))).split("}");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));

        for (String string : str) {


        JFlat flatMe = new JFlat(string);


        //directly write the JSON document to CSV
        //flatMe.json2Sheet().write2csv("D:\\My File_674335\\fromJSON.csv");
        flatMe.json2Sheet().headerSeparator().write2csv("D:\\My File_674335\\csvConversion\\fromJSON.csv");

        //directly write the JSON document to CSV but with delimiter
        //flatMe.json2Sheet().write2csv("/path/to/destination/file.json", '|');   
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: updated my attempts

Comment: Can you also include the complete error message that you are getting? Also, how are you inputting those 2 json? Since I only saw 1 json file being inputted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse .txt to .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526679/parse-txt-to-csv)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 15 column 3 path $.AA_FCTR.PRI_ICD_CD
 at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:58)

Comment: Input is through inputJSON.json or a text file containing all the jsons in

Comment: Why not read the file one line at a time into an array instead of reading the whole file?