# Printing out with Byte[] Java

Tags: java

I am having an issue with the use of FileOutputStream.write. I guess it does not let me write to a file using a String, so I tried changing the string to the primitive data type Byte[]. Now when I try to print it out, using the following for loop, it prints out result the as many times as the input is long.

Say I have 21345, instead of just printing out 21345 if prints out this below:

`21345
21345
21345
21345
21345`

```
for(int a=0; a<machineWord.length(); a++){
    byte[] input = machineWord.getBytes();
    out.write(input);
}
```

EDIT: I was reading Byte as an array, so I thought I had to loop through each position on Byte, to output the code. I just deleted the for loop which solved the problem.

Comment: which... makes sense? It just does what you're asking

Comment: You could write string to File, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java

Comment: it is doing what you want...it does not require a for loop ... just keep loop body .... you are writing it `length` times here length is 5 so it writes 5 times...

Answer (score 0):

Because your looping through every character in the string and writing the String to the file each time. The `getBytes()` method returns a `byte[]` array representation of the String. You only need to write it one time.

```
// write the String to the file.
out.write(machineWord.getBytes());
```