# i want to send data from an array to a txt file

Tags: java, netbeans

```
String[][] EmployeeArray = new String [1000][25];
```

this is my array, it has all the info I need in it already but I want to send all the data from here into an text file called **EmployeeFile**. How should I do this?

Comment: serialize it into json

Comment: In what form you want to have data from that array in file? Should it be comma-separated-values (CVS) file, or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I save a String to a text file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can Serialize it, or even better do some json decorations/formatting and then write that to a file...

jusing json could be as simple as:

```
String[][] x = { { "0-0", "0-1", "0-2" }, { "1-0", "1-1", "1-2" }, { "2-0", "2-1, "2-2" } };
try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("my2DArray.json")) {
     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
     gson.toJson(x, writer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to loop over your array and create a single string containing your data to be written to the file. This is done so you can add the new line characters where you want them.

```
String fileContents = new String();

for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<25; j++) {
    fileContents += EmployeeArray[i][j]
  }
  fileContents += "\n";
}
```

The code above is very basic and it is ment to demonstrate the basic idea.
It would be more efficient to use a StringBuilder and I guess there are 100 ways to improve those lines further.

Then you can use the following method to write to the file:

```
public boolean writeFile(String data, String path) {
    try {
        byte[] encoded = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        java.nio.file.Files.write(Paths.get(path), 
            encoded, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
        return true;
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    return false;
}
```

You should **be careful** with the options **StandardOpenOption.CREATE** and **StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING**. They will overwrite existing files.
Somtimes you need to append to the file, adjust accordingly.

The StandardOpenOption documentation can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html). **StandardOperation.APPEND** comes in handy for logging purposes.

Also note that the character set used is **UTF8**. It is generally a good idea to use UTF8 if it covers your needs. If you get strange characters in your data you might need to also adjust accordingly.