# How do I export all files without any IDs or duplicate IDs to a text file in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jtable

I have a java program which is like a search engine where you can type any keyword into the search bar and it will find a matching keyword in the MySQL database and pull up all those entries into a Jtable. There are about 50000 data entries so if I were to type 1.456, all entries that contain this keyword will come up. I have an ID column whereby every entry has a unique ID. I want to be able to export any entries that do not have an ID to a seperate text file. And also if possible, export duplicate IDs.

Comment: "ID row" - like a star schema?  I think you can accomplish this with an appropriate JOIN.

Comment: Sorry I mean column

Comment: Sounds like it should be a primary key.  Every row should have one.

Comment: If every entry has a unique ID , how would any entries have missing or duplicate IDs?

Comment: Exactly - a primary key is required and must be unique.  You realize that your approach is limited.  Lucene/Solr are real search engines.  Try those.

Comment: It's not a primary key, it's just a a unique ID for each entity. It's for a crime database, the IDs are unique identifiers for the crime data. There are around 50,000 entities here and there are some that do not have any IDs. I need to be able to export the entities that don't have any IDs to a .txt file

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the set and build up a map of ID->count as integer. In the end you can take all the ones with count > 1 and export them.
While building up that map, if you encounter an entry with no key, add it to a separate collection.

Another possibility would be to do it in a custom select right in the DB. Maybe the count function provides what you are looking for: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-function.php

This is an example for storing in a text file: [How do I save a String to a text file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java)