# How do I alter the value of my label, and keep that new value even after the program has closed

Tags: java, serialization, label

I'm designing a banking program, and I have a balance label that shows the balance after each transaction, however, after I close the program it defaults back to it original value

I've tried setting the value of the label to the new desired value, but the program defaults back to the original each time

```
double newbalance = Double.parseDouble(balance) + Double.parseDouble(deposit);
lbl_ActualBalance.setText(String.valueOf(newbalance));
```

I expected the value of the label to change indefinitely but it keeps defaulting

Comment: If you want to persist the value after the program exits, you need to store it on disk, e.g. in a text file.

Comment: how would i go about doing that

Comment: [How do I save a String to a text file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

You could also Serialize it. Have the class implement the `Serializable` interface then when the data is updated just call a `save()` method:

```
public void save()
    {   
       FileOutputStream fos = null;
       ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try
        {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("saveFile.data");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(this);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
              foo.close();
              oos.close();
        }
    }
```

then when you load the program up, just call some form of `load()` method

```
public void load() {
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try
    {
        fis = new FileInputStream("saveFile.data");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        lbl_ActualBalance.setText((double)(ois.readObject().lbl_ActualBalance));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.our.ptintln("Error: " + e.getmessage();
    }
    finally
    {
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    }
}
```

This way you can easily save/load everything about your system.