# How to send mail attachment created from string in java?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I have a scenario where i get a big error log string, which is not good idea to send it as mail text.
So , we need to generate text file and send it as mail attachment.

If there is any way to create a file in memory and send it as attachment that would be good instead of creating physical file?

Following is my code:

```
void sendEmail(String errorlog) {
    try {
        MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
            messageHelper.setFrom("sachin@gmail.com"); 
            messageHelper.setTo(InternetAddress.parse("akash@gmail.com"));
            messageHelper.setSubject("error log");
            messageHelper.setText(" Please find log attachment:");

            File <somehow crate text file from parameterized string>

            messageHelper.addAttachment("log.ext",file);

        };
        javaMailSender.send(messagePreparator);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `MimeMessagePreparator`?

Comment: org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator

Answer (score 1):

There is an another addAtachment method in the MimeMessageHelper which can help you to add attachment without creating file.

```
addAttachment(String attachmentFilename, InputStreamSource inputStreamSource)
```

You can easily create inputStream with given string

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

After that create inputStreamResourceSource which implements inputStreamSource

```
addAttachment("log.ext",new InputStreamResource(inputStream));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `FileUtils.writeStringToFile()` from Apache Commons IO.

[How do I save a String to a text file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

So I have had the same issue and none of these answers worked for me - when trying to use MimeMessageHelper [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58974148/10789836) I was getting an "Passed-in resource contains an open stream" error. In the end, I was able to solve this problem by preparing body of my e-mail step by step, like this:

```java
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
BodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes()));                          
attachmentBodyPart.setFileName("filename.ext");
attachmentBodyPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);

mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);
```

Note that when mixing up this approach with using MimeMessageHelper, `mimeMessage.setContent()` will overwrite any content added by MimeMessageHelper (so for example text you want to send in body of your e-mail), which I solved by adding to `multipart` additional BodyPart that contained the text I wanted to send inside my e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

I host a **Spring Boot application in Docker** on my VPS. This code will work on a local system whilst developing in an IDE **as well as if the .JAR-file is wrapped in a Docker image**:

Example case:

I like to get a PDF. The PDf document is located at `static/docs/not-a-porn.PDF`.

1.) Wire the class `ResourceLoader` and `JavaMailSender`.

```java
private final JavaMailSender emailSender;
private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

public MyService(@Autowired JavaMailSender emailSender, @Autowired ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    this.emailSender = emailSender;    
    this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
}
```

2.) Create a resource by `pathOfAttachment` (`String`).

```java
String pathOfAttachment = "classpath:static/docs/not-a-porn.PDF"
Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource(pathOfAttachment);
```

`Resource` is an interface that extends `InputStreamSource` as you can see in the documentation:

`public interface Resource extends InputStreamSource`

Source: `org.springframework.core.io` [Link to documentation (click here)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html)

3.) Define e-mail's metadata.

```java
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

helper.setFrom(Text.EMAIL_COMPANY);
helper.setTo("myMail@gmail.com");
helper.setSubject("MySubject");
helper.setText("Hello from Spring Boot application", true);
```

3.) Attach file to e-mail attachments.

```java
helper.addAttachment(resource.getFilename(), resource);
```

4.) Send e-mail.

```java
this.emailSender.send(message);
```