# How to save all the System.out.println present in the code in a .txt file?

Tags: java, json, selenium, file, automation

Running my code, I would like to save all the System.out.println() in a file.

For example:

```
System.out.println("Save this!");
```

I would need a file .txt in which is stored the string "Save this!".

Someone could help me?

Regards,

Francesco Campanile

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java

Comment: `java -jar MY_PROGRAM.jar | tee -a my_file.txt` (assuming you're not on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Use this to Write console to a file.

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(
        new FileOutputStream("output.txt", true), true);
System.setOut(out);
```

The output file will be on your project's root directory